# How to attach to process on .NET console app in Docker container running in WSL2?

Tags: docker, visual-studio, .net-core, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I have a C# .NET CORE console application running in a Docker container, which runs in WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04.

Now I would like to use Visual Studio (in Windows) to debug that C# console app running in that Docker container.

How can I do it in Visual Studio?
I have tried using the method suggested in [here](https://medium.com/criteo-engineering/wsl-visual-studio-attaching-launching-a-linux-net-core-application-on-my-window-10-ab21c179702d), but unsuccessful when I tried to connect to Remote System

[image]

Can anyone point me how to debug C# code by attaching to a process running in a Docker container hosted in WSL2?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your container is running.
2. Select Debug > Attach process(Make sure "Show processes for all users" is checked)
   [image: Attach to Process]
   2.1 Connection type: Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)
   2.2 Connection target: your distro name
   2.3 Attach to: Managed (.NET Core for Unix) code
3. Navigate to "dotnet" process, your application should be there

Answer (score 0):

The attach to process dialog now supports connecting to a process in a container: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/attach-to-process-running-in-docker-container?view=vs-2022#attach-to-a-process-running-on-a-linux-docker-container
[image]

Also, when the container is running through the local Docker Desktop you can start the attach to a process dialog from the Containers window in VS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/view-and-diagnose-containers?view=vs-2022#attach-the-debugger-to-a-process
[image]